# Show that the simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{d^2-1}$ is $[d-1; \overline{1, 2d-1}]$ for $d \geq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that the simple continued fraction of $\sqrt{d^2-1}$ is $[d-1; \overline{1, 2d-1}]$ for $d \geq 2$

For some reason I keep getting the wrong answers. I think it's because I am not setting my initial values correctly. What are $q_0, p_0, q_1, p_1$?

Answer (score 2):

**Terms of the Continued Fraction**

Since $\left\lfloor\sqrt{d^2-1}\right\rfloor=d-1$, the first term is $d-1$. Subtracting $d-1$ and inverting gives
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{d^2-1}-(d-1)}=\frac{\sqrt{d^2-1}+(d-1)}{2d-2}\tag{1}
$$
The floor of the term on the right is $1$; so the next term is $1$. Subtracting $1$ and inverting gives
$$
\frac{2d-2}{\sqrt{d^2-1}-(d-1)}=\sqrt{d^2-1}+(d-1)\tag{2}
$$
The floor of the term on the right is $2d-2$, so the next term is $2d-2$.  Subtracting $2d-2$ and inverting, we get back to $(1)$. Thus, the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d^2-1}$ is
$$
\left\{d-1;\overline{1,2d-2}\right\}\tag{3}
$$

---

**Approximants Example**

To compute the approximants for the continued fraction of $\sqrt{15}$, use $d=4$. As computed above, the continued fraction is $\left\{3;\overline{1,6}\right\}$:
$$
\begin{array}{r|rr|rr}
c_n&&&3&1&6&1&6&1&6\\\hline
p_n&0&1&3&4&27&31&213&244&1677\\
q_n&1&0&1&1&7&8&55&63&433
\end{array}
$$
where $p_n=c_np_{n-1}+p_{n-2}$ and $q_n=c_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}$ .

Comment: How is it found what the right hand side expressions in 1) and 2) are approximate to though ? How can one see that $ \tfrac{\sqrt{d^2-1}+(d-1)}{2d-2} \approx\frac{2d-1-\frac1{2d}}{2d-2} $. Is there some Theorem at work here ? I'm just a little confused, I'm only a learner..

Comment: @Voltron: the approximation $\sqrt{d^2-1}\approx d-\frac1{2d}$ is the only approximation used.

Comment: Ah okay, I see now the rest just input that approximation, but how was that original approximation obtained, if you don't mind my asking ?

Comment: There are several ways to get this approximation: Binomial Theorem and Taylor Series are a couple. Probably the easiest is to note that for small $x$, $(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2\approx1+2x$. Thus, for small $x$, $(1+x)^{1/2}\approx1+\frac x2$. Therefore, $$\sqrt{d^2-1}=d\left(1-\frac1{d^2}\right)^{1/2}\approx d\left(1-\frac1{2d^2}\right)=d-\frac1{2d}$$ This can be checked with $$\left(d-\frac1{2d}\right)^2=d^2-1+\frac1{4d^2}$$

Comment: Since all we really need is $\left\lfloor\sqrt{d^2-1}\right\rfloor=d-1$, I have removed the approximations and replaced with floor expressions.

Comment: Thank you , your explanation was very informative :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be $[d-1;\overline{1,2d-2}],$ in other words replace your $2d-1$ by $2d-2.$ Doing this works in the case of $d=2.$

$1+1/x$ where $x=1+1/(2+x)$ which gives $x=(1-\sqrt{3})/2$ then $1+1/x=\sqrt{3}.$

I believe in the case of any integer squareroot the period starts immediately after the initial integer part of the radical, and that the last term of the repeating part is always twice the integer part.

Comment: (+1) your extrapolation is correct. I've not looked into your last statement, though.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, and would be easy to check as above by finding solution $y$ to $y=1+1/(2d-2+y).$

Comment: @robjohn I saw that last statement about continued fractions for $\sqrt{n}$ in some number theory book, and didn't go through the proof myself.